# PHP rand to include random web page section on page refresh

Tags: php, arrays

PHP rand to include random web page section on page refresh. I needed some php code to randomly include a `<section>` containing links at the bottom of my blog posts. This code works .

```
<?php
 $files = array("../inc/links/blog-links-bottom.php",
                "../inc/links/blog-links-bottom-1.php",
                "../inc/links/blog-links-bottom-2",
                "../inc/links/blog-links-bottom-3");
 include $files[array_rand($files)];
?>
```

But it does not always include the `<section>` ie its missing. Also it does not always insert a new `<section>` on page refresh which is what I wanted. I'm not very familiar with php.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

```
$files = array("../inc/links/blog-links-bottom.php",
               "../inc/links/blog-links-bottom-1.php",
               "../inc/links/blog-links-bottom-2",
               "../inc/links/blog-links-bottom-3");
include($files[rand(0,(count($files)-1))]);
```

**Explained**

Filling the array like this will give you this kind of array:

```
array(
    [0] => "../inc/links/blog-links-bottom.php",
    ...
)
```

You need to get a random key between 0 (lowest index) and the highest index (count of array layers, minus one) to target a random layer in your array.

Comment: You missed a ")" at the end.
'include($files[rand(0,(count($files)-1))]);'

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`include $files[rand(0,4)];`

or simply

`include array_rand($files);`

To make clear what you did wrong:

`$files` is a nummeric array, so it has elements like `$files[0], $files[1] etc..`.

`array_rand` returns a random element from an array.

So in your case `array_rand($files)` returns for instance `"../inc/links/blog-links-bottom-1.php"`. In combining the two, your are calling `$files["../inc/links/blog-links-bottom-1.php"]`and that doesn't exist.